# input box not getting refreshed after confirm is false in jquery on

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-partialview

i have a jquery datepicker that gets added dynamically in ajax request through a partial view.
i have to do a js check after the date is selected so i have came up with this-

> $(document).ready(function () {
>
> ```
>     $(document).on('change', 'input[name="ReportDate"]', function () {
>         if ($(this).attr('data-isDccmAndReady') == 'True') {
>
>             var d = new Date();
>             var currentDate = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + +d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
>
>             var dateSelected = $(this).val();
>
>             if (new Date(dateSelected) > new Date(currentDate)) {
>                 var answer = confirm("The contract has been already reported, are you sure you wish to continue?");
>
>                 if (answer) {
>                     return true;
>                 } else {
>                  //this is correctly resetting the value
>                     $(this).val($(this).attr('data-originalReportDateVal'));//$(this).val() gives the old and the correct value.  
>                     return false;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>
>         return false;
>     });
> });
>  </script>
> ```

the issue when you select **cancel** in the confirm box the datepicker value do not reverts to the old value in html or do not refreshes.

Comment: Try `$(this).val($(this).data('originalReportDateVal'));` If it doesn't work, please show your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That worked with a workaround

> var id = $(this).attr('id');
>
> $('#' +id).val($(this).attr('data-originalReportDateVal'));

i am not sure why it doesn't work directly with

> $(this).val($(this).attr('data-originalReportDateVal'));

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-refresh

```
       if (new Date(dateSelected) > new Date(currentDate)) {
            var answer = confirm("The contract has been already reported, are you sure you wish to continue?");

            if (answer) {
                return true;
            } else {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('data-originalReportDateVal'));
                $(this).datepicker( "refresh" ); // <-- Try this (or with the right datepicker selector)
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: sorry it didn't work!! it has something to do with the jquery 'on' method because when i changed it to  $("input[name='ReportDate']").change(function () { all the logic} it works but the issue with this option is it just fire once.

Comment: the  `change` method is just an alias for the `on('change')` method... so no this won't just fire once

Comment: that worked with a work around. I have posted my answer.